# Add filename column to dataframe from multiple json imports

Tags: r, json

I've got multiple `.json` files which consist of dates. I would like to import all the `.json` files in R to create one dataframe and add a column that consist of the filenames.

`2020-06-15.json`:

```
[{"title":"Moral Machine","title_link":"http://moralmachine.mit.edu/"}]
```

`2020-06-16.json`:

```
[{"title":"De Monitor","title_link":"http://demonitor.ncrv.nl/"}]
```

Then I create a dataframe

```
test_path <- "data"
test_files <- list.files(test_path, pattern = "*.json")

test_files %>%
  map_df(~fromJSON(file.path(test_path, .), flatten = TRUE))
```

Desired output:

```
          title                   title_link       file_name
1 Moral Machine http://moralmachine.mit.edu/ 2020-06-15.json
2    De Monitor    http://demonitor.ncrv.nl/ 2020-06-16.json
```

Comment: does any json file contain just one observation?

Answer (score 0):

Using `rbindlist` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

file_names <- list.files(path = test_path, pattern = '.*json')

data_list <- lapply(file_names, function(z){
  dat <- myFunction(z) #your function to read and clean json files
  dat$file_name <- z
  return(dat)
})

combined_data <- rbindlist(l = data_list, use.names = T, fill = T)
```

Since I don't know the structure of your JSON file, I'm assuming you have a function named `myFunction` to read and clean up the data.

Comment: I added the content of my two example .json files, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(jsonlite)

test_files_full <- list.files(test_path, pattern = "*.json",full.names=TRUE) # to get the full path string

test_files <- list.files(test_path, pattern = "*.json")

t(sapply(seq_along(test_files), function(x) 
            c(fromJSON(test_files_full[x]),file_name=test_files[x])))
```

gives,

```
     title           title_link                     file_name        
[1,] "Moral Machine" "http://moralmachine.mit.edu/" "2020-06-15.json"
[2,] "De Monitor"    "http://demonitor.ncrv.nl/"    "2020-06-16.json"
```